# Keycloak 12.0.4 with Oauth2-proxy to Authenticate NGINX requests

Tags: nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy, oauth2-proxy

I am using a reverse proxy to access some of my applications with NGINX. I currently protect my reverse proxies with Oauth2-proxy and authorize accessing users with Azure AD. Instead of using Azure AD directly with Oauth2-proxy, I decided to use Keycloak as IdP. I installed Keycloak and it is working fine now. I also added Azure AD as a provider and it works fine. What I want to do now is, I want to use Keycloak as a provider in the oauth2-proxy module. I would also like to define allowed_groups in the oauth2-proxy config file and define a different access group for each reverse proxy and make group-based access management. How can I do that? I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.